# Is there any online based data mining software?

Tags: java, data-mining, classification, weka

I found out there is a open source mining software in Java, which is called WEKA. It has some useful classification methods as well as other methods that helps people who are not related to data-mining areas to get started with mining.

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Nowadays, there are a lot of transitions from desktop applications to web based applications due to cloud. I was wondering why there aren't standard (general) classification solutions on the web that WEKA does, and many other features that it supports.

Is it because it is hard to make software through the web that does the similar thing? Or is it because the data mining area is unprofitable without going deeper into the subject that probably fits to the specific area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's any harder to have something like Weka that can have an online UI or interface, but Data Mining algorithms are quite process-intensive, meaning it wouldn't make much sense to do that unless your data set were quite small.... but then, Data Mining probably won't make sense as Data Mining is much more useful for very large data sets.

From my experience with Data Mining, I would certainly agree with you that you must have very specific knowledge into your subject area to be able to do meaningful mining.

By the way, you may get some "Minuses" because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google offers something like this, a very simple online prediction solution.

Plus, RapidMiner has a professional version, IIRC called RapidAnalytics, that could qualify as "online". But you probably mean "web2.0".

In my opinion, it will not work very well. Because there is no such thing as automatic data mining. It requires domain and method knowledge and experimenting. And lots of processing power.